# WP7(1): System.Windows.debug.resources not found?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7.1

When I run my WP7.1 app, I get this error.

> File or assembly name 'System.Windows.debug.resources, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=en-US, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e', or one of its dependencies, was not found.'

Any idea what is happening?

Comment: At what point do you get the error? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I still haven't found a decent answer to this. These guys see the same issue:
http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/85779/571045.aspx It's never a problem at runtime as far as I know - it only ever shows when you have "break on exception thrown" enabled for "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" in Visual Studio.

Comment: I had the same problem but it disappeared when i unchecked "Thrown" in Debug->Exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience that could happen if you create or use some Framework Element (or any Dependency Object for that matter) in a non-UI Thread.

Simply check that all UI-related tasks are performed on the UI thread, and if not, use `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` to post them to the main thread.

Answer (score -2):

There is a simple workaround for this just create your custom CheckBox control by inheriting windows phone silverlight CheckBox and override ToString() method like this:

```
public class MyCheckBox:CheckBox 
{ 
    public override string ToString() 
    { 
        return string.Empty; 
    } 
}
```

see more here:
[Framework Exceptions in Windows Phone](http://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/post/2012/01/06/Framework-Exceptions-in-Windows-Phone.aspx)